How to access "page setup" properties in Visio using VSTO
Can anyone help me out with the above issue?. I have checked the Visio VSTO websites and could not find any codes that accesses the needed page properties.

I need to access the "page setup" properties of the page using VSTO.
and the following needs to be changed.
Under the "Page Size" tab: Select Let Visio expand the page as needed.
Under the "Printer paper" tab: need to change the change the size.

Much thanks.

            try
            {
                var pages = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Pages;

                foreach (var pg in pages)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page page = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page)pg;

                    page. // ?? <- how to access the page setup??
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


I think these options are available in the PageSheet, and not directly exposed as properties of the "page" object. You can try this:
page.PageSheet.Cells("PageWidth").Formula
page.PageSheet.Cells("PageHeight").Formula
page.PageSheet.Cells("DrawingResizeType").Formula


Also, there is Macro Recorder feature in Visio; when you are unsure how do a specific thing using API, you can turn it on, do that thing manually, and then examine the generated VBA code.

Thanks Nikolay, This solves the problem. And thanks for the direction on the Macro Recorder and the PageSheet.
